# MySQL JOIN blindness

Tags: mysql, join

This query

```
   SELECT station_id, station_name, 
        COUNT(event_station) as `total_visit_count` 
           FROM taps AS t 
           JOIN event_stations AS s 
              ON t.event_station = s.station_id 
                 WHERE s.event_id=6 
                    GROUP BY s.station_id 
                    ORDER BY s.station_id;
```

returns

```
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
| station_id | station_name | total_visit_count |
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
|          5 | Station one  |                24 |
|          6 | Station two  |                35 |
|          7 | St. Pancras  |                34 |
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

which is just fine.

However, there are some stations in `taps` which have not been visited and I would like them to be shown with a `total_visit_count` of zer0.

```
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
| station_id | station_name | total_visit_count |
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
|          5 | Station one  |                24 |
|          6 | Station two  |                35 |
|          7 | St. Pancras  |                34 |
|          8 | Station four |                 0 |
+------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

How do I rewrite my query to to that? I imagine some kind of JOIN is required, but I can't quite see it :-(

---

[Update]

```
describe event_Stations;
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| station_id   | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| event_id     | int(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| station_name | text       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| allocated    | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.20 sec)


describe taps;

+---------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field         | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+---------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| tag_id        | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| time_stamp    | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| event_station | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| device_id     | text      | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| device_type   | text      | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| event_id      | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
+---------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)


select * from event_stations where event_id=6;
+------------+----------+-----------------+-----------+
| station_id | event_id | station_name    | allocated |
+------------+----------+-----------------+-----------+
|          5 |        6 | Station one     |         0 |
|          6 |        6 | Station two     |         0 |
|          7 |        6 | St. Pancras     |         0 |
|          8 |        6 | Station three   |         0 |
|          9 |        6 | Station four    |         0 |
|         10 |        6 | Station five    |         0 |
|         11 |        6 | Station six     |         0 |
|         12 |        6 | Station seven   |         0 |
|         13 |        6 | Station eight   |         0 |
|         14 |        6 | Station nine    |         0 |
|         15 |        6 | Station  ten    |         0 |
|         16 |        6 | Station  eleven |         0 |
+------------+----------+-----------------+-----------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: please post table description also

Comment: I figured it isn't necessary, as all the relevant fields are already named. I thought that if I added that, the question would look to messy. Is there any information missing?

Comment: It didn't work, but does now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, swap the order of your join, so the primary table is sorted first (this is for organizational purposes only).

Then, use a **LEFT JOIN** to accomplish what you're looking for.  This will ensure you pull all `event_stations` records (the left portion of the join), even if there is no corresponding record in the `taps` table (the right portion of the join).  In place of the missing taps, you'll get NULL values.

**COUNT** will ignore nulls in aggregate, so will only return the count of non-null records.  Thus, it will return 0 for your missing event_stations records.

```
SELECT
    station_id, 
    station_name, 
    COUNT(event_station) as `total_visit_count` 
FROM event_stations AS s 
   LEFT JOIN taps AS t
      ON t.event_station = s.station_id 
WHERE s.event_id = 6
GROUP BY s.station_id 
ORDER BY s.station_id;
```

Alternatively, you could just use a **RIGHT JOIN** with your original join order.  I personally don't like doing that, though, because I'm a LTR reader (first in order is more important).